# Getting error with New version of Jhipster 0.11 with hazelcast

Tags: jhipster

I am working on Jhipster.Today i have move our project to you latest version and now i am getting exception on userResource.Some of Function are working on this file but when i am try to login with facebook and google then get exception.Because with google and Facebook have login user without password.

Exception is

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.application.gom.web.rest.user.UserResource
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:295) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:194) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:157) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.web.SerializationHelper.toData(SerializationHelper.java:38) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$HazelcastHttpSession.writeObject(WebFilter.java:508) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$HazelcastHttpSession.access$1000(WebFilter.java:395) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:605) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.application.gom.web.rest.user.UserResource
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor330.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:204) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:176) ~[hazelcast-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.BasicErrorController - com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.application.gom.web.rest.user.UserResource
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.BasicErrorController - com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.application.gom.web.rest.user.UserResource
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have this exception with the initial project.

The only change done on the 0.11 release is the addition of the @RolesAllowed(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN) annotation on the getUser method.

Could you try to remove it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: But may be it given some "com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException" exception.

Comment: This actual exception :-[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder

Comment: Resolve My issue..this issue due to HttpSession. Now i have create project without httpsession then it work fine for me.may be having exception in HttpSession in jhipster project.